# How to get MapPanes from Google Maps JS API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to identify the overlay layer pane on a google map, so that I can customize the css on it.

In the [API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapPanes), Google describes a way to get the map panes, with:

```
google.maps.MapPanes()
```

But the MapPanes method/object doesn't exist! You can see in the console of [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/bozdoz/pen/Cfsna), that the function/object is `undefined`.

I have tried these versions of the google API as well: 3.exp, 3.16, 2.

Any way I can get the overlay layer?  Any reason why these methods aren't working?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  It's a legitimate question!  Described in the API docs, but doesn't work in practice.  Other mapping applications have ways of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how the API describes to get the `MapPanes` object of an instance of `google.maps.Map`.

You get the `MapPanes` object by adding a custom overlay and accessing it in it's prototype methods:

```
var CustomOverlay = function() {};

CustomOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
CustomOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
 console.log(this.getPanes());
};

var x = new CustomOverlay();
x.setMap(map); //map is an instance of google.maps.Map
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#OverlayView

**EDIT:**

Here's a painful, but necessary, way to get the mapPanes object without a custom overlay:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(); //create your map object

var DummyOverlay = function(map) { };
DummyOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
DummyOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
 var self = this;
 if(!map.getMapPanes) {
   map.getMapPanes = function() {
      return self.getPanes();
   };
 }
};

//add the dummy overlay to the map so it's draw method is called
(new DummyOverlay()).setMap(map);

//at this point, you can use map.getMapPanes() to get the MapPanes object like so
var panes = map.getMapPanes();
```

You'll see that you need to create a "fake" custom overlay that doesn't actually do anything, except add a new method - `getMapPanes()` to your `map` object. This is only example code, modify it as necessary to your exact code.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake on the map.getPanes() claim.  The other method still doesn't work.  I'll try your suggestion.  I wonder if there's a way of doing it without adding a blank custom overlay though.

Comment: There is not as tjis method is only available on `google.map.OverlayView` objects - very irritating I know

Comment: What about the google.maps.MapPane object?  Any idea why that doesn't seem to actually exist?

Btw, your solution works if you add a draw method as well.

Comment: It's a description  of the MapPanes object's properties, it's not the actual object that you get by doing this.getPanes() inside an overlayview

Comment: But MapPanes doesn't exist!  Also, it does appear to be the actual object you get by doing this.getPanes() inside an OverlayView.

Comment: That's correct, it doesn't exist - in the API docs it uses the google.maps.MapPanes namespace to describe the objects properties - floatPane, shadowPane, etc.